# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Ivan (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: insert into Users (FirstName) values (Ivan)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1769)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1698)
        at com.example.blagodari.Models.DBhelper.addUser(DBhelper.java:93)
        at com.example.blagodari.MainActivity.Tap1(MainActivity.java:46)
```

Пишет, что ошибки в DBhelper.java:93 и MainActivity.java:46

DBhelper.java:93:

```
 database.execSQL(sql);
```

MainActivity.java:46

```
 db.addUser(user);
```

Я подозреваю, что я что-то сделал не так при создании таблицы бд. Вот мой код:

```
String user_sql = "Create table " + TABLE_USERS + " ( " + KEY_ID_USERS + " integer primary key, " + USER_NAME +
                    " nvarchar(128), " + USER_SURNAME + " nvarchar(128), " + USER_PASSWORD + " varchar(50), " +
                    USER_EMAIL + " varchar(128), " + USER_ACCOUNT_DATE_CREATED + " integer)";
            db.execSQL(user_sql);
```

Вот моя функция, отвечающая за добавление пользователя в таблицу Users:

```
public void addUser(User user){
        SQLiteDatabase database=getWritableDatabase();
        String name=user.getFirstName();
        String surname=user.getSurname();
        String passwd=user.getPassword();
        String email=user.getEmail().toLowerCase();
        long date= user.getDate_created();
        String sql="insert into "+TABLE_USERS+" ("+USER_NAME+") values ("+name+")";
        database.execSQL(sql);
        sql="insert into "+TABLE_USERS+" ("+USER_SURNAME+") values ("+surname+")";
        database.execSQL(sql);
        sql="insert into "+TABLE_USERS+" ("+USER_PASSWORD+") values ("+passwd+")";
        database.execSQL(sql);
        sql="insert into "+TABLE_USERS+" ("+USER_EMAIL+") values ("+email+")";
        database.execSQL(sql);
        sql="insert into "+TABLE_USERS+" ("+USER_ACCOUNT_DATE_CREATED+") values ("+date+")";
        database.execSQL(sql);
    }
```

Сначала вставлял все одним запросом, потом в надежде решил разделить, но увы...

Comment: а вы пробовали выполнять запросы по одному а не все сразу?

Comment: @Andrew вы имеете в виду запрос в функции addUser()? Там же и так они выполняются по одному

Comment: да запрос добавления, насколько я вижу проблема в том что вы пытаетесь обратится к столбцу IVAN, хотя его по логике нету, я бы вам советовал посмотреть на бд и на таблицу, что там есть за столбцы, и что вы создали, так же я вам советую перед добавлением в таблицу посмотреть при помощи вывода в логи что вы собираетесь записать в таблицу, чтобы быть уверенным что все записывается верно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на

```
no such column: Ivan (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: insert into Users (FirstName) values (Ivan)
```

Все, что включается в `values` должно идти в одинарных кавычках, приведите ваш код к тому, чтобы в итоговом SQL было так:

```
insert into Users (FirstName) values ('Ivan')
```

или

```
insert into Users (FirstName) values ('Ivan','Emelya',...)
```

для множественной вставки.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Странно, вроде заходил на сайт https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-insert/ , там без кавычек написано

Comment: А, все, понял, не туда посмотрел...

Comment: Да, еще можете ответ галкой отметить, чтобы другие участники понимали, что это решает вашу проблему.

Comment: все, сделано)))